# Weird : Can't ping another machine by its hostname but ONLY from a specific machine

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

I have a machineA, ip 192.168.0.171. I can ping it from all the machines on the network, but not from machineB - by hostname. Using its IP address, it is pingable.

From MachineB, I can ping all the other machines, no problem, as well. SO the issue is that everything works as it should, EXCEPT I can't ping machineA from machineB when using its hostname, ie ping machineA.

What's weird is that if I do,say, dig @192.168.0.1 (my router, running a dnsmasq server)-- dig @192.168.0.1 machineA A, the name resolution is done correctly. Of course, here I specificalyl specified the DNS server to query, but then the name resolution IS actually done correctly on the lan, except for machineA. Additionally, doing a simple nmap machineA, the name is also resolved correctly.

Can anybody help figure this out?

I can edit /etc/hosts, of course, but that's not understanding the issue, which is what I want to do, so if you have any suggestions or clues, I'd appreciate that

Comment: dig and nslookup sometimes don't use the same resolver as things like ping which does so it more accurately mimics typical application behaviour.  When you type `ping machineA` what is the IP address say? You could also run `sudo -e trace=network -s 1500 strace ping MachineA` and paste that on pastebin (https://pastebin.com/) or also `sudo -e trace=file ping MachineA` and that could give you a hint at what it's doing

Comment: it doesn't say anything. It doesn't output anything. It's just not resolving it. As for the sudo -e trace. It's showing me the help page, something isn't right. But I just ran strace by itself (strace ping kali --> machineA's name is kali. I posted the output onto the link you gave. Here it is : https://pastebin.com/DaYqNWF5 . What should I be looking for exactly? Curiously, there seemed to be some kind of resolution, as I found kali's IP - 192.168.0.171 listed in there

Comment: how about an strace from a working computer?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vsjzFYHz . I was a little limited as to the working machine part. My other laptop I lent to someone else for the week. My options were my phone or tablet, but that might not be the best idea, since it's a different OS still. What I did was I ran this from a virtual machine ON the machine that isn't working. And, get this, it's working. I can ping kali from there, believe or not. https://pastebin.com/vsjzFYHz. Still not ideal, but I hope it's ok. the IP of the VM is 10.10.10.10 and is routed through the host machine (192.168.0.56 (or 10.10.10.1)) via a virtual switch)

Comment: can you compare the contents of /etc/resolv.conf? Also, can you put the other pastebin back? You don't need to put an expiry

Comment: I feel like you typed kali.lan in this example but something else in your previous paste or somewhere you are using a dns search suffix and not realizing it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fDuEag0C ; Here it is. Indeed on the initial pastebin I did ping kali, whereas with the second one I did kali.lan. But it doesn't make any difference on this machine. On the second machine (the VM, where it works), ping kali doesn't work either, but ping kali.lan does. On the non-working machine, neither does. This new pastebin has the output of sudo strace ping kali.lan this time - not working.

Comment: The contents of /etc/resolv.conf are the same on both : They only have the line 'nameserver 127.0.0.53' essentially. It's debian, this is controlled and overwritten by systemd's resolved. So I edited that file instead on the VM when I first set it up last week (and now also on the host machine, but it doesn't make any difference in its case). /etc/systemd/resolved.conf - on the VM : DNS=192.168.0.1/25

Comment: I set it that way on the VM quite a while ago, or it wouldn't've resolved any names - not only on LAN, but the internet at large [ I mean, it didn't have to be the router's address - I could've used an external DNS resolver, but then it wouldn't've resolved LAN hostnames]. As for the host machine, I shouldn't have to change anything, since all the rest of the LAN is resolved correctly aside from this kali.lan hostname. Just to test it, though, I have now changed /etc/systemd/resolved.conf on the host machine as well, but it still doesn't make a difference.

Comment: you're sure ping works when using the ip address on the non-working machine `192.168.0.66` ? Might as well paste an strace of that too.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/F3Y44YEz . Haha yes...Like I said in the title, it's very weird. It has me completely puzzled. The way it got my attention is that I could ssh into user@192.168.0.171 no problem, but couldn't ssh into user@kali. I first I thought it might be something to do with the firewall, but it isn't. They're disabled on the two machines.

Comment: Hmm if you caught it using ssh, does the contents of ~/.ssh/config differ on the machines?

Comment: no, they're the same. GatewayPorts yes
ForwardAgent yes